# How can I write a unit test for Loading AngularJS Components With RequireJS After Application Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I write a unit testing for angular js applications.
the bootstrap for this app loading dynamically.
when I write the unit test for this always error happen like didn't find the module or unknown provider $rootScope <- $rootScopeProvider.
I write the test using karma and jasmine.

Comment: can you show your code and the log errors ?

Comment: unfortunately  I can't now,

Comment: it show it can't see the module

Comment: beforeEach(module('XXX')) it show that XXX doesn't registered or misspelled